Delete a specific field meeting specific conditions from an object in a collection
I have searched the web for possible solutions. Basically a field needs to be deleted where the id of an object in an array of objects meets a specific condition.
As a newbie to Mongodb I am not sure where exactly to look for relevant examples.
I want to delete the object where id = 0. The language used will be Javascript.
Not quite sure how to go about it though.
Look at the picture below . In red is an id, each registered user will have their own id. Each user will have a cart associated with their id. In the cart is productsInCart-->products which has fields like id, price etc.
So what happens is the users id is selected then the product(object) deleted where the specific product id = 0. The product id is shown with an arrow in the picture and I guess the Object to be deleted would the one at index = 0 also shown by a red arrow. The same could be done with any other Object at index 1 or 2 or anywhere.
I tried using $pull,$unset and the basics found online but the thing is  that accessing the product id field requires a very specific command which I am not sure how to write it in Javscript . In sql it would be something Delete Object Where user id = new ObjectId("66a35c99784aa722b15c9801") and product id = 0


can you share a sample document in https://mongoplayground.net/maybe

@cmgchess not sure how to go about it. Should i copy the document and paste it there?

@cmgchess
https://mongoplayground.net/p/zliMzeZvHx6

is there a reason why carts is an array. can it contain multiple { "productsInCart" : [...]}

This question is similar to: MongoDB, remove object from array. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ray Sadly straight off the bat  as shown in the documentation and examples it does not work.
I guess its half way there, probably like the last step of multiple steps  ,  but I already tried all these things before coming here. The problem here is that the object to be deleted is nested deep in the cart object. Plus each registered user has their own cart so its Delete product Where _id =  _id: new ObjectId("66a35c99784aa722b15c9801") and id = 0 , so its: cart-->productsinCart-->product-->id.  Now how to do this in Javascript is where I am stuck as a newbie

Avoid creating nested array fields. This is considered an anti-pattern and introduces unnecessary complexity to the query. Consider keeping just the cart level.
[
  {
    ...,
    "cart": [
      {
        "product": {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "iPad 11inch",
          "imageUrl": "./images/ipad.jpg",
          "title": "Apples",
          "description": "Apples are <span class=\"label label-info\">25 CHF each</span>",
          "price": 25
        },
        "quantity": 2
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
]

You can simplify the query to be like this:
db.collection.update({
  "cart.product.id": 0
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "cart": {
      "product.id": 0
    }
  }
})

Mongo Playground

If you need to stick with your current schema, you will need a sophisticated aggregation pipeline. You need to iterate the cart array with $map, then use $filter to iterate through the productsInCart array to perform the filter. Finally, use $mergeObjects to update the result back to cart level.
db.collection.update({
  "cart.productsInCart.product.id": 0
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "cart": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$cart",
          "as": "c",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$c",
              {
                "productsInCart": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$c.productsInCart",
                    "as": "p",
                    "cond": {
                      "$ne": [
                        "$$p.product.id",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
